# Find what datasets are used by what report in SQL Server Report Server Catalog

Tags: reporting-services

I had a project with many shared datasets, many of which were not used any longer.

I wanted to know which one of the deployed data sets are used and which are not.

So how can you list all the reports is a SSRS folder and all the data sets that are used in the reports?

Answer (score 2):

All the reports and all the data sets are stored in the Catalog table.

Some trial and error led me to conclude that the Type column value of 2 lists all the reports and the type of 8 lists all the data sets.

There is a many to many table called DataSets which has 2 foreign keys relations to the Catalog table. The LinkId relates to a dataset in the Catalog table, and the ItemId relates to a report in the Catalog table.

Here is my query:

```
declare @path as varchar(100) = '/Use Your Folder Path Here%';

with
    Catalog_DataSets
    as (select c.ItemID as DataSetItemId,
               c.Path as DataSetPath,
               c.Name as DataSetName               
        from dbo.Catalog as c
        where c.Type = 8
        and c.Path like @path),

    Catalog_Reports
    as (select c.ItemID as ReportItemId,
               c.Path as ReportPath,
               c.Name as ReportName
        from dbo.Catalog as c
        where c.Type = 2
        and c.Path like @path),

    ReportDataSetUsage
    as (select ds.ItemID as ReportItemId,
               ds.LinkID as DataSetItemId,
               ds.Name as UsageName
        from dbo.DataSets as ds)

select ds.DataSetItemId,
       ds.DataSetPath,
       ds.DataSetName,
       count(rep.ReportItemId) as UsedByReportsCount
from Catalog_DataSets as ds
left join ReportDataSetUsage as ds_to_report
    on ds_to_report.DataSetItemId = ds.DataSetItemId
left join Catalog_Reports as rep
    on rep.ReportItemId = ds_to_report.ReportItemId
group by ds.DataSetItemId,
         ds.DataSetPath,
         ds.DataSetName
```

Now you can use this to find dependency between reports and data sets, to find data sets that are not needed any longer as they are not used by any reports etc.